# How to use ts-node regardless of errors?

Tags: typescript, ts-node

I've got some trouble with ts-node when I develop.

I want to test something, so as you know, comment is my best friend.
But with ts-node I've got this error :

```
'foo' is declared but its value is never read
```

But I don't want to comment all my unused variables because theses variables are in fact useful for the code after testing.

So, is there a solution like `ts-node --please-let-me-work` to ignore these error ?

Thanks ;)

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?

Answer (score 50):

`ts-node` has a `--transpile-only` (or `-T`) argument. It will ignore all type errors and just build your project.

My 2022 suggestion for this to set up `esbuild` instead. Not a plug and play experience, but extremely fast. We use `esbuild` for (constant) building during development, and rely on other tools to report type errors.

Answer (score 10):

If you use `ts-node`, you can use this alternative :

`$ ts-node-transpile-only filename.ts`

It will run the typescript file without checking errors.

Comment: Do you mean to use this ubuntu [package](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jammy/man1/ts-node-transpile-only.1.html)?

Answer (score 8):

Use `-T` or `--transpileOnly` and make sure its passed in *before* the file name. So:

```
ts-node -T someFile.ts
```

## References

- https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-node#skip-typechecking
- https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-node#transpileonly

Answer (score 0):

`ts-node --logError` helped me. Now, instead of terminating the app, it just shows an error.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/ts-node#logerror

Though, it works only for type checking and other "light" errors. If there is a syntax error or something that ts-node really can't process, it will fail.